Remove % sign and round default chart display format to 2 decimal places
I'm trying to remove the percentage sign from displaying on my chart, below is the code that needs changing.
if show_open_high == true
    label.new(current_bar_index, h + distance, style = label.style_none, text = (positive_sign) + str.tostring(above_perc, format = format.percent), textcolor = open_high_color)//, yloc = yloc.abovebar)

I tried different formats; none were displaying properly

You can use a custom format.
str.tostring(above_perc, format = '#.##')

